# insert ManyToMany relation data using Django serializers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

following are my details.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    EmployeeId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='EmployeeId')
    EmployeeCode = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    EmployeeStatus = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    CreatedDate = models.DateField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    CreatedUser = models.ForeignKey(Login, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='CreatedUser',
                                related_name='CreatedUser', null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    Device = models.ManyToManyField(Device, through='EmployeeDevice')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Employee"


class EmployeeDevice(models.Model):
    EmpDeviceId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='EmpDeviceId')
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, db_column='EmployeeId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Device = models.ForeignKey(Device, db_column='DeviceId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "EmployeeDevice"
```

serializer.py

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def employee_update(request):
    try:
        login = Login.objects.get(UserId=1)
        emp_serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if emp_serializer.is_valid():
            emp_serializer.save()
            device = Device.objects.all()
            for devicedata in device:
               emp_serializer.Device.add(devicedata)

        else:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(emp_serializer.errors)
            return Response(emp_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(repr(ex))
        return Response({'Exception': repr(ex)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is my code
but it's not working properly
device details are not saving showing error
"Exception": "AttributeError("'EmployeeSerializer' object has no attribute 'Device'",)"
and also I want to save the CreatedDate and  CreatedUser with the existing data.
and also how can i get the primary key value after inserting?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you set attribute "through" for the "Device" Field, you changed the name that you can access to Devices. according to django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) you can remove attribute or change it to "through='Device'"

Comment: HI @babak gholamirad , EmployeeDevice  one of my Model. ,  i didnt understand the concept.. , The same logic works while using an employee object.. but using serializer how can i  modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `EmployeeSerializer` you can override your `create` method. First create and then save the `Employee` after that you can add `Device` to them.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        emp_obj = Employee.objects.create(**validated_data)
        emp_obj.save()
        device = Device.objects.all()
        for devicedata in device:
            emp_obj.Device.add(devicedata.id)
        return emp_obj
```

`views.py`

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def employee_update(request):
    try:
        login = Login.objects.get(UserId=1)
        emp_serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if emp_serializer.is_valid():
            emp_serializer.save()
            # REMOVE UNNECESSARY CODE FROM HERE
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(emp_serializer.errors)
            return Response(emp_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(repr(ex))
        return Response({'Exception': repr(ex)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Moreover if you want only specific field in `Response` you can parse `serializer.data` and return them as required.